# How can I verify my custom domain using domains.google.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

How can I verify my custom domain using `domains.google.com` if
it doesn't allow duplicate keys and firebase hosting requires a duplicated key entry?

[image]

And firebase requires 2 text entries with same host.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DNS records in Google Domains can contain multiple values. So while you can only have a single TXT record for a given name, it can contain all the values you need to validate the domain for Firebase Hosting.

The steps are:

1. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> link next to your TXT record.
2. Click the small <kbd>+</kbd> next to the (last) value.
3. Enter the new value for the existing record
4. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

Here's one of our domains, after step 1:

[image: Editing a multi-valued TXT record in Google Domains]

Comment: That looks like the right direction. We get `Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes.` at the `Verifying ownership` though on Firebase console's relevant page.

Comment: Ok, with firebase it generates every time different code, so you have to be timely. Now co-ordinating with the domain owner it went fine.

Comment: Where did you get the 23.235.33.171 from?

Comment: That's in the email you get from Firebase *after* it has verified the TXT records.

Comment: Did you have to put both the A and CNAME records in there?

Comment: If the domain is still not verified after following the procedure above, wait a few minutes, it may take a moment to synch your google domains. I was having errors and just re-verifying the connected domain after a few mins solved it.