# Getting an error when setting a custom domain for a Firebase Web App

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have acquired some domain from `godaddy.com` and now I want to deploy my Firebase Web App to this domain.

In the first step of "***setting a custom domain***", I needed to verify my `godaddy.com` account by adding two TXT records. The problem is, the tutorial doesn't specify the name in those records, only the value.

Here are the records as I filled them in the `godaddy.com` in the manage DNS section:

[image]

[image]

I read in some blogs that the name should be `@` and the value should be the same as in the tutorial. I did so, now I'm getting the following error.

> There was a problem connecting your custom domain. Please contact
>   support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) as the message says?

Comment: Yes, didn't get any response yet. I thought that meanwhile someone could help me here.

Comment: You'll have a much better chance of getting help if you show what you've put in your DNS records instead of describing it. For example, here are the settings in one of my domains (on Google Domains in this case): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020463/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-using-domains-google-com/39020649#39020649

Comment: I added them to the question.

Comment: Looks correct to me at first glance. You'll probably just have to wait for support to get back to you (unless somebody spots a mistake before that).

Comment: I had a lot of issues as well setting up a custom domain with Firebase. I have custom host and my issue was that I needed to add quotes around each TXT record.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer is GoDaddy specific since the OP is using `godaddy.com`

In 2018, this process seems straightforward.
There are three steps:
[image]
Step one is self explanitory.

In step 2 of the , you have to put in your google-site-verification in the DNS record.
[image]

In step 3 you must delete ALL previous A type records and enter the two IP addresses they give you as new A type records.
[image]

After about 12 hours google finally provisioned my ssl certificate.